# Realtime tracking of GPS arduino module in Google Maps

Tags: android, arduino, gps, iot

How to directly get GPS arduino module data to Android application to track the GPS arduino module realtime location in Google Maps?. Can we track the GPS module's position using its physical address and since GPS module does not require Internet so how to get the realtime location of the GPS module?

Comment: What gave you the idea that GPS can send data?

Comment: using gsm module you can send the data!!!!!

Comment: But GSM isn't GPS.

Answer (score 0):

What is the GPS Module which you going to use. Because normal GPS Module can't upload Location data. You need some network interface. It may be Wifi of GSM. If you use Wifi as Network interface you can use ESP8266 powered Arduino board such as NodeMCU or GSM Shield. Then you can get realtime location updates connecting Arduino with Firebase or such kind of Realtime database.